# Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Stack Overflow has lots of questions about configuring virtual hosts, rewrite rules, and .htaccess files. Should I be routinely voting to migrate these to ServerFault?

Comment: Most of the rewrite questions I see are to do with SEO. Webmasters might be a better place.

Comment: Serverfault will get grouchy if you send them all manner of routine rewrite rules questions.  That site is really for sysadmins.

Comment: If it's the same question being asked and it's already been answered here, flag as a duplicate.  But if it's a new question that is more or less generic enough to have value to another person in future, I would think that it's relevant for SO.  Understanding configuration files is a part of the development and deployment process.

Comment: According to Jeff Atwood via SO's blog: [It’s tricky, because any given URL rewriting question could legitimately be on topic for multiple sites, each with a different core audience:

Server Fault (sysadmins),
Stack Overflow (programmers),
Webmasters](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/). Based on that: "Yes". Webserver config in general is a grey-er area - but if it's trivial it's probably on topic for SO (I'm trying to use x, why doesn't this tutorial-config work?), and if it's not it's better placed on serverfault (IMO).

Comment: @intracept I generally don't read these questions, because I don't have much expertise in webserver configuration. I could probably answer rewrite questions because they're basically just regex questions. But I wonder about questions about configuring virtual hosts -- that seems more appropriate for Webmasters than SO.

Comment: @Barmar I've had my butt saved once or twice by a generic-ish answer to these types of questions on SO, so that type do occasionally do have value :)  But I agree with you on configuration of virtual hosts.

Comment: The Pee Wee Herman Rule talks about whether the questioner is a valuable addition to the community. But flip it around: is our community of value to the questioner? When I recommend that someone ask a question on a different site, it's not just to get rid of him, but also because I think he's more likely to get a good answer at the alternate site. Maybe that's not as much a concern, since there's so much overlap between the communities (e.g. there are enough webmasters on SO that he'll get a good answer).

Comment: Dupe on meta.se http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so I personally despise these questions, but many seem to think they are a mini language and therefore can stay.

Comment: As someone that often answers questions in the `.htaccess` spectrum: Most of the questions asked are very light-weight config questions, with a strong link to the programming things they are doing. I am not a sysadmin, and I am perfectly able to answer those questions. Rewriting urls is part of these light-weight config questions. When questions are getting more configy, in the area of optimization or setting up semi-complex things, I usually politely point at ServerFault and suggest they might have an easier time finding an answer there. I never suggest migration because it's a grey area.

Comment: **Configuration is not programming.** Would firewall rules be ontopic too, and then configuring passwords in `/etc/shadow` manually, too? You are calling functions in the background there, too. With my programmer hat, it starts becoming interesting if it involves a system or POSIX call. With my sysadmin hat, this is one of interesting questions. It was a good idea to bring it up for discussion, thanks, +1.

Comment: @Robert: "Serverfault will get grouchy if you send them all manner of routine rewrite rules questions..." - how about [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) when appropriate? And personally (I might be in a minority), but I'm less concerned about hurting SF's feelings *if* its on-topic for them. Tough rocks if they don't like it. I would not complain if SF sent programming questions to SO. Rules are rules and they are intended to be followed.

Comment: @jww Webmasters [is not appropriate for server configuration](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it's a site aimed at (possibly non-technical) website administrators. It deals with questions "about search engine optimization (SEO), domains, and web-hosting." [webapps.se] is similarly not the right exchange to post to, it deals with end-user usage of web applications, not server configuration.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that the other sites are so narrowly focused that SO is effectively the dumping ground for everything that doesn't fit their very specific areas.

Comment: @Barmar, it's not about SO being a dumping ground, rather it's about acknowledging that programming and software development, in terms of *implementation* (i.e. not for Programmers.SE) is more than just "coding".

Answer (score 25):

It's always felt like a grey area in regards to Web server configuration files. I've had this question for a long time. System administrators do routinely setup and manage Web servers, and they're oftentimes quite skilled in managing their configuration, which is where this line of thinking comes from. But configuration files are really just abstractions for real, actual code. Here's the thought process I went through to come to the conclusion that **yes, these things are on topic here:**

Take the Jetty Web server, for instance. It's written in Java, and we configure it using XML markup. But the XML uses names like "org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration". That's clearly a Java package and class name. The documentation shows Java methods, with typed arguments like "java.lang.String" and return types with different "org.eclipse" class names. The XML is merely read by Jetty, which uses the reflection API to call the actual class methods, passing in data from the XML configuration. In short, the XML is an abstraction layer.

So does this mean system administrators should learn Java so they understand this syntax and the inner-workings of Jetty and the JVM?  Maybe they do, and if they do, does that mean programmers should completely forget there exists a JVM?

Also, as an aside, Jetty can be configured using real code, and it's sometimes embedded in applications with no XML configuration whatsoever. Hence, a system administrator needing to reconfigure such a server would need to know a little Java.

Another great example is Node.js. It has several built in Web servers. Should system administrators learn JavaScript so they can load balance a Socket.IO server, for instance?

The point of these examples is to show that these tasks involve both programming and system administration knowledge. The two worlds overlap significantly. Therefore, it would be disingenuous to say that these things are not something a majority of professional programmers will deal with in their careers.

In short, just because something *may* be on topic somewhere else doesn't mean it should be off topic here. Shog9 wrote a great blog post on this issue, titled [Respect the community -- your own, and others'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/):

> As members of a community, your first loyalty should be to *that* community. When evaluating a question, you shouldn’t be looking to push it off on some other site; instead, ask if it could be appropriate and on-topic for you, the experts who the author decided to ask. **Be a bit jealous of your site** – don’t blithely turn askers away simply because their question could be asked somewhere else. Don’t hit them over the head with your scope, help them tailor their question to fit into it – and if that means your site’s scope overlaps a bit with another site’s, so be it.

Hope this helps. Great question!

Comment: I have no doubt that good system administrators also need to have programming skills. I've been a sysadmin, and one of the reasons I was a good one was because I was also a programmer. But that doesn't mean that anything someone with programming skills does belongs on SO. I think the distinction between programming and configuring is probably whether the language you're using is Turing-equivalent. A bash script is, but XML generally isn't (there's nothing preventing XML being used as the way to represent source code in a programming language, but I don't think any exist).

Comment: Yeh, @Barmar, not advocating that anything remotely programming related is on-topic here as that would be brutal, but Turing or not, in Jetty, you're basically calling Java class methods in XML. Abstractions are powerful things. With that said, I'm not sure we can define a clear boundary here, and it's likely going to be something we evaluate on a case by case basis.

Comment: Now, I just thought of a way to complicate this even more: Some web servers take things a step farther and abstract out the XML with a nice front-end GUI. You make changes in the Web interface, and it generates the XML. Does that fall out of scope of Stack Overflow? I want to say it does, but it seems like just another layer of abstraction and just shows how deep this rabbit hole goes.  So perhaps a good baseline is this:  Are you a *hacker* of the system, or are you a *user* of the system?

Comment: `I have no doubt that good system administrators also need to have programming skills. I've been a sysadmin, and one of the reasons I was a good one was because I was also a programmer. But that doesn't mean that anything someone with programming skills does belongs on SO` -> **That**. Also, I see Shog9 misquoted here. Surely, his sentence could be interpreted the other way around, too. It is not fair to try to immitate that even such "high authority" is on your side and who thinks it otherwise than you is *respectless*.

Comment: I don't think it's even much of a grey area.  Rewrite rules are a form of programming.  You are programming the web server.

Comment: @WarrenDew - So what this really comes down to is something that some sysadmins I've known don't want to admit -- *that being a sysadmin does involve some forms of coding.*.

Comment: Pff, with that even a simple grep or find command usage is programming since you pass rules and patterns for the search... Heck, no, this is not programming. This does not make you any good programmer, what-so-ever just as adding a user to my system as a programmer does not make me a sysadmin.

Comment: Yeh, @FinalContest, as much as I enjoy using grep to make my life more enjoyable, I'd have to agree it's definitely not programming. It might still fit under the on-topic umbrella of programming tools, but I'll leave that debate for another meta question. It's clear the line is very blurry...

Comment: I do not think it is any blurry, really. Even the Linux foundation shows all this under the "Linux user" training series umbrella as opposed to "Linux developer". I cannot see any of this rule stuff in the famous "Linux Programming" guides either. It is a user, at best power user topic rather than development.

Comment: @FinalContest, my guess is that it doesn't seem blurry to you because you might be involved in developing applications that are more or less self-contained. For those of us who develop applications that have multiple components, which typically involve different layers of the system or are distributed across a network, how everything is deployed and how the environment is or should be configured affects directly the programming of our application(s). Then the line is very blurry.

Answer (score 4):

As a Linux/Unix systems administrator—diid develop & still develop, but not as a focus—I believe that questions about rewrite rules, redirects and `.htaccess` files are on topic. The way I set my Linux boxes up is nobody but administrators get to mess with the deeper configs. The rewrite rules, redirects and `.htaccess` stuff all falls on the developers I grant basic user access to server to.

The larger issue is what can a coder/developer deal with. And 9 times out of 10 they are dealing with  rewrite rules, redirects and `.htaccess` stuff connected to a coding task they have. I don’t have the time to bother with stuff like that so let them deal with it.

The other coding aspect comes from Apache `mod_rewrite` rewrite rules that use regex: The whole concept of regex is a coding concept & a coding skill unto itself. It’s not easy to deal with & can be hard to debug even for pros, so I again see that as a coder/developer task.

Now the larger gray area is overall server configuration. That would definitely be better suited for [`Server Fault`](http://serverfault.com), but those are rare from my perspective. And I mostly flag those as questions that should be moved to [`Server Fault`](http://serverfault.com).

So in the construct of this question with my perspective as a Linux/Unix systems administrator who doesn’t grant administrator access to developers, I believe that anything a basic user can do on a server without administrator access falls in the realm of coding either directly or indirectly.  And I believe the accommodations that exist in Apache (via `.htaccess`) and PHP (via `ini_set` & such) to address developer needs validate this approach.

**UDPATE:** And doing a quick search on a few Stack Exchange sites reveal the community for these topics by the numbers. All searches were for `RewriteRule` which is specific to Apache `mod_rewrite`.

- [**Stack Overflow:**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ReWriteRule) 60,000+ results.
- [**Server Fault:**](https://serverfault.com/search?q=RewriteRule) 4,440+ results.
- [**Pro Webmasters:**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=RewriteRule) 1,160+ results.
- [**Super User:**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=RewriteRule) 138 results.

Now, I am not saying that “mob rules” should dictate appropriateness, but the gigantic rift between where questions & answers occur between **Stack Overflow** and the other sites pretty much speaks for themselves.

Additionally, [Apache’s official documentation on the use `.htaccess` files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#when) explicitly explains their purpose as a configuration tool for non-administrators:

> `.htaccess` files should be used in a case where the content providers
>   need to make configuration changes to the server on a per-directory
>   basis, but do not have root access on the server system. In the event
>   that the server administrator is not willing to make frequent
>   configuration changes, it might be desirable to permit individual
>   users to make these changes in `.htaccess` files for themselves. This
>   is particularly true, for example, in cases where ISPs are hosting
>   multiple user sites on a single machine, and want their users to be
>   able to alter their configuration.

Comment: **You want the numbers to speak for yourself, not themselves**. If you allow them to speak for themselves, you can see that people have asked many such questions here, but the OP is asking about whether this should be changed, and I do not think Barmar wants to hear the "leave it here because that is how it partially worked" mantra.

Comment: That is nonsense. With that any pdf viewer and reading pdf is coding because you can use glob and all that to lokalize the result, or even using a simple editor by sysadmins to find something in a simple text file. This is **clearly** user and/or sysadmin job, thus better suited to such dedicated SE sites for that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

As a web developer, I often have to configure web servers (Apache, IIS, nginx, WEBrick, Thin, etc) **for my development environment**. *I am not* a professional "system and network administrator". It's not my expertise.

### Production vs Development Environments

According to [Server Fault's guidelines](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) (summarized):

> Server Fault is a site for system and network administrators needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a [**professional capacity**](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/4111/what-is-a-professional-capacity).
>
> If your question is about…
>
> - Server and Workstation operating systems, hardware, and software.
>
> and it is not about…
>
> - **Anything in a home or development environment**
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Notice the "professional capacity" link, which says:

> Over the years the Server Fault community has evolved a rough consensus
>   definition of what that phrase means. There are two broad categories
>   we assess new questions against regarding 'professional capacity'.
>
> 1. The system being asked about is a production system.
>
> **Production Systems**
>
> This is more of an exclusionary line. Questions that fail this test
>   are also likely one or more of:
>
> - Development systems (likely failing the *anything in a home setting* point in the FAQ, and debatably more topical on
>     Stack Overflow)
>
> We've found that scoping "professional capacity" to just production
>   systems does a great job of keeping questions definitely topical.
>
> Of these the *development systems* item gets us the most pushback.
>   There are very good reasons we eliminate these systems from
>   consideration:
>
> - The [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) states that "software tools commonly used by programmers" is topical.

The link goes on with more reasons as to why "development environments" are ***off-topic*** for Server Fault.

### Configuring Dev Systems is *Off-Topic* for SF, but *On-Topic* for SO

**Please don't migrate** any and all server configuration and networking questions over to Server Fault. Because as it says above in Server Fault's own meta, development environments are ***off-topic*** there...but they're certainly *on-topic* here on Stack Overflow, under the "programmer's tools" clause.

Comment: Based on your first two sentences, you should probably ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/). Or, change the SO policy since server/site configuration is *not* on topic here per [SO Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help). And nearly every command, program and package falls under "programmer's tools", which makes it nearly useless as a criteria.

Comment: @jww there need to be clearer and updated guidelines for these type of questions, which is why we're discussing them here. Also, there are already a ton of [tag:heroku] and other Platform as a Service questions here on SO. What if I'm setting up a WEBrick or Thin server for my ***dev environment***? I need to get this set up for ***development*** purposes. It does not go on [su], nor [webmasters.se], nor on [webapps.se] (*especially not the last two*).

Comment: @ Cupcake - "there need to be clearer and updated guidelines for these type of questions". +1. It would be great if the Help Center explicitly stated it. That would make it a policy, and I'd be happy to oblige.

Comment: @ Cupcake - This one still blows my mind: [Coverity Scan Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766027/coverity-scan-setup). How is a static analysis tool off-topic for Stack Overflow? If a static analysis tool is off-topic, then website configuration *is* surely off-topic.

Comment: @jww start a feature request for it. I'll vote for it. If the help center explicitly said something like "server configuration by developers for dev and production environments are OK, by sysadmin questions are not", that would be great.

Comment: @jww regarding Coverity, it's not my domain expertise, so I can't judge it either way. If you feel that it is on-topic, then ask another Meta question about it.

Comment: @jww, you seem to be forming your general idea regarding what's on and off topic on the basis that [one of your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17766027/372643) seems to have been unduly closed. I don't know Coverty, but this looks on-topic to me, in the same line as other tools like GitHub or similar. (I did vote to re-open it a while back, but somehow this doesn't show and I can't vote again.) Don't let yourself be bullied by the closing zealots :-)

Comment: Btw, although I don't dispute there may have been an increase in the number of bad question over the past year or so, there also seems to be an increase in excessive votes to close. Some seem to want to close certain topics that could be on topic, but don't affect them personally, rather than letting others ask and receive help (for their development problem). Software development is vast. Because I don't need or use `.htaccess` doesn't mean others don't. I've learnt to ignore the tags I don't want to read (including some programming languages I don't use), others might try to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [top answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261747/2444812) makes some good arguments and there is grey area and overlap.

I think it is also important to ask: Where would the question get the best answers?

There are many questions with bad (or misleading answers) regarding web server configuration / redirects etc. on SO. If the question stays on Stack Overflow, is it likely that it will get a bad answer by someone who knows enough to answer but not enough to answer well? (And these answers will get upvoted, the voting does not prevent wrong answers from getting upvoted). Is such a question really helpful? Wouldn't it be better to have fewer questions with better written answers by people who actually have a deep knowledge of the topic? Of course, there are lots of people on SO who could answer well, but will they bother for questions that are really basic or rather address system administration?

So, I would always (for the specific question)

1. Check if question is a duplicate. Follow procedure for duplicates.
2. Check if question is badly written: Leave helpful comment and mark for deletion or downvote.
3. If specific to programming, leave it.
4. Only if it is a good question about system administration and actually new, propose to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're talking about voting to migrate questions to ServerFault. Doing it systematically is certainly not a good idea. [They're unlikely to like it](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/3853/47187).

Secondly, you're more asking about whether questions about virtual hosts, rewrite rules, and .htaccess files are on-topic here on SO (whether they should be migrated to SF seems to be a secondary concern), that is, whether they should be closed, not just migrated.

I'll leave aside the fact that configuring rewrite rules can be considered as a form of programming, using a DSL, but I'd like to address a different point. (Conversely, Spring XML configurations could be considered off-topic as not programming, yet they're not, thankfully.)

Instead of looking at these questions purely based on their topic, perhaps trying to figure out the context into which they're asked can help make a decision. For example, SF is about "*managing computer systems in a professional capacity*", perhaps we should see SO as "*handling "IT stuff" in a software developer capacity*" (I can't find a better way to word this right now).

Software development and programming encompass a wide variety of domains. Some programming questions are purely contained within the programming domain, and are not influenced by many sysadmin aspects: these are the questions where how the application is to be used and deployed doesn't really matter (besides the type of OS, perhaps). There are plenty of those, and they are indeed on-topic.

There is however another category of problem that pertain to the deployment of the overall system that is being developed. How the software should be developed, and which programming solutions to choose, can be directly affected by these. Yet, they're not pure programming problems.

I think many questions about virtual hosts, rewrite rules, and .htaccess fall into this category. They may not be programming questions as such, but as a developer, you need to know what's possible and how to do it. (I'm not talking about institutions where people have multiple roles at the same time.) This is particularly true for projects that involve multiple entities, remote parties, network communications, containers, some web communication, ... In many cases, the application that is being developed requires *all* the pieces involved to function as a whole. In this case, questions that look like configuration question at first can be directly relevant to the implementation of the application (or set thereof).

Many of these questions wouldn't be a good fit for SF (often not sufficiently sysadmin-professional) or even SU (often far too specific).

I know a good question should be purely self-contained, but I try to read those within the context of software development:<sup>1</sup> could answers to such questions be useful from this point of view, to other software engineers or programmers? Does a programmer need to know this to develop their application? Under these circumstances, I tend to consider configuration or sysadmin-related questions on-topic on SO. (I'll admit there remains a part of subjectivity anyway.)

To me, this doesn't just apply to questions about virtual hosts, rewrite rules, and .htaccess, which are all effectively web-related (some of which might be considered for migration to Webmasters.SE). I've answered a number of questions on the [ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssl) tag that also fall into this grey area unfortunately.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24500316/372643) is a recent question that can be answered by configuration or by programming. A common category of questions is about certificate errors. Most users who ask this sort of questions don't really know what they're asking. A typical question would be "I get an error that says the certificate is invalid, how do I make my application work?". We see quite often here (or on various blogs around) solutions that use [*programming*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1828840/372643) to provide a solution that is not secure, whereas an equally simple [*configuration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10406233/372643) solution would have been sufficient, without introducing a security vulnerability. In addition, many questions about SSL/TLS require the developers to have an understanding of the deployment conditions of the overall system on which they are working. A number of questions on this tag are borderline on-topic, but I must admit I'm generally on the more tolerant side, trying to be helpful to other developers who might have the same problem. This being said, there are still questions on this tag that I consider to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24596569/372643), in which case I vote to close them.

After that, if I think a question is on-topic on multiple SE sites, I'd only vote to move if I think the question is likely to get a better answer on the other site. (This can happen for more specialised sites, like DBA.SE.)

<sub>1: Note that the context where the question ask matters. For example, the [a question asking about the difference between prawns and shrimps](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/45226/what-is-the-difference-between-a-prawn-and-a-shrimp) would be a very different question on a cooking site and on a biology site (or even [English Language and Usage site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118604/what-s-the-difference-between-shrimp-and-prawn)).</sub>