# Are website configurations on-topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons

Are website configuration questions on-topic at Stack Overflow? These questions are often accompanied by a {apache|nginx} config snippet; or a certificate validation error (but without code, without the certificate or chain, and without a hostname or URL).

Here are some reasons I've been told they are on-topic:

- The question was asked by a programmer
- The question was asked by a programmer for debugging
- The question was asked by a programmer who developed the website
- The question was asked by a programmer and the site worked for HTTP (but not HTTPS)
- The question was asked by a programmer who used a common programming to to do something
- The question was asked by a programmer who used a tool in an SDK (like `keytool`) to do something
- Webservers are programs
- Webservers run programs

The back story is I usually vote to close them (and point folks Server Fault, Webmasters and sometimes Web Apps), but I often catch some blowback. The blowback comes from the person asking the question and even some senior members.

Sorry I have to ask. At times I feel like I'm doing something wrong. I want to ensure the person asking the questions is being treated fairly, and I want to ensure I am understanding Stack Overflow policies correctly.

Comment: @Robert - would you mind if I attempted to re-open with an edit? The linked question does not have an accepted answer, and I am definitely looking for a definitive answer on the site's policy.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - would you mind if I attempted to re-open with an edit? The linked question does not have an accepted answer, and I am definitely looking for a definitive answer on the site's policy.

Comment: What are you trying to find out that isn't already covered by that answer over there, accepted or not?  28 other users approve of his message.

Comment: @Robert - I don't see anything about site/server configuration being on-topic in [SO Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help), so its not SO policy. Plus, there are a few sites that specifically deal with the subject matter, including [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/). I think the linked question, which asked about sending to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), was too narrow, did not address site policy, and did not have an accepted answer.

Comment: Stack Overflow accepts questions about tools commonly used for programming.  Web servers are commonly used by programmers to implement software applications.  The metaphor doesn't extend forever, however; Visual Studio installation questions are on-topic, but SQL Server installation is not.  There's plenty of prior art about this if you care to look, and nobody's going to give you a hard and fast rule to follow.  Mod rewrite questions have been on-topic forever, and they're web server configuration.  So, there it is.

Comment: Also, you ***cannot*** ask web server configuration questions on [sf] if they're for ***development*** environments. Server Fault [*explicitly* disallows it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262746/456814).

Comment: @jww, I guess when you talk about blowback you're talking about [such a comment I made](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24500316/how-to-add-sslc-certificates-in-a-unix-server#comment38090269_24500316). Please don't get me wrong, I'm certainly not trying to offend or be conflictual. I just get the impression that [you have yourself been the unfortunate victim of that excessive closing behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17766027/372643), and have  since adopted a stricter approach too. Instead, I merely suggest that you don't let your decisions be influenced so much by that incident.