# Please add verbiage in Help Center to reflect policy on site/server configurations

Tags: support, help-center

Please add verbiage in the Help Center to reflect policy on site/server configuration questions.

While the {on|off}-topic-ness has been discussed before on the Meta's, there is no clear policy in the Help Center governing it. The closest is a leap from "software tools commonly used by programmers".

The leap from "software tools commonly used by programmers" leaves a bit to be desired for several reasons:

- Nearly all commands, tools and packages are used by programmers, so they all meet the criteria of "software tools commonly used by programmers". Its a useless criteria.
- Web servers and their configurations are not common for many programmers. I'm a C/C++/ObjC guy, so web servers are not a common tool to me and similar programmers.
- Site users are in the middle of the endless debates.

The one that bothers me the most is users being in the middle of it. I often move to close them as off topic; and that's not fair to the users if I am not following the site's policies or if I don't know what the [missing] policies are.

Additionally, server and site configurations appear to be more appropriate for other sites in the Stack Exchange network, including [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) and [Webmaster Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Finally, there seems to be confusion in applying the "software tools commonly used by programmers" rule. For example, [Coverity Scan Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17766027/coverity-scan-setup) was closed as off-topic. Its not clear to me if a static analysis tool is *not* considered a programming tool; or if its *not* considered a common tool. Either way, it seems to be very relevant for programmers.

---

Here are some related references.

- [Are website configurations on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262881/are-website-configurations-on-topic)
- [Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic)
- [Are htaccess questions ever on-topic at SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81032/are-htaccess-questions-ever-on-topic-at-so)
- [Apache configuration/.htaccess questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6235/apache-configuration-htaccess-questions-esp-mod-rewrite-so-or-sf)

Comment: On a related subject, I think it would be helpful if the current close reasons reflected the topicality of server configuration question on SO too, because I see too many such questions blindly closed with "*Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault*", even though such questions in the context of dev environments are *explicitly* off-topic at [sf].

Comment: @Cupcake That such a question is off-topic on ServerFault doesn't make it any more on-topic on SO, and ServerFault evaluates questions on their own merits, using their own scope.

Comment: ([This](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266612/372643) might be of interest in the context of this question.)