# Where can I ask system administration related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I was asking about cron job, got voted down and saying its related to system administration, so where to go to ask for it?

I want to ask if I have this situation:

> 1. Shared Hosting Solution is selected (Godaddy)
> 2. Want to do cron jobs.
>
> For example, if a user got scheduled a meeting with another person in
>   certain time, I want my site to remind both person about the meeting
>   by email.
>
> What do you guys think is the best option? Do you think its better
>   just talk to api to schedule in the client's calendar system?

Comment: If your question is about **professional** system administration, and you're a professional system administrator (not a software developer), then your question belongs on [sf].

Comment: @Cupcake I think the main question is about when it's the kind of sysadmin task you need to do or at least know about *as a developer*, but it's not a good fit for SF.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a system administration related question, as it's basically asking "should I use a Cron job?" - with too little information to answer it either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What kind of questions belong on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275082/what-kind-of-questions-belong-on-stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: @gnat do you see Super User / Server Fault in any of the answers there? We could definitely use a canonical "should I post on SO/SU/SF", but the one you linked to isn't one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find clear boundaries for what questions are asked on Stack Overflow, Super User, Webmasters, and Server Fault?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329182/where-can-i-find-clear-boundaries-for-what-questions-are-asked-on-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 4):

In summary, I'm increasingly leaning more towards wanting to allow questions on the subject of system administration from a developer's perspective<sup>(*)</sup>. **However**, such questions would still have to match the other criteria: clear, not too broad, not likely to lead to a subjective discussion. *Unfortunately*, considering the way you've phrased you sample question, I don't think that would be a good fit for Stack Overflow even if the subject of sysadmin was considered on-topic. The answers would be likely to be very subjective or at least very dependent on what your users are expecting or meant to expect from your broader system.

<sup>(*) Beware this is my opinion, not necessarily endorsed by others. I wouldn't be surprised to get a few downvotes here. (Some people vote to close them at first sight.)</sup>

---

More generally...

- If you have a good question, and if you're acting as a professional system administrator (but not having a development-related question), consider using [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), and remember to read their own guidelines first. As a rule of thumb, if you feel it's for professional sysadmin, is not relevant to a software project you're developing, and Server Fault users don't like it there, it's not a good idea to ask the question on Stack Overflow anyway. (Perhaps Super User might be a better place, but check their guidelines too.)
- If you have a good question that is about system administration *and* if you're doing this specifically within the context of software development (and expect to be answered in that context), I think such a question *should* be on-topic on Stack Overflow. (Again, this is my current opinion, certainly not official policy, or at least not clearly if it is.)

  I think such questions should fall, at least loosely, under the "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" or perhaps "*a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development*". I just wish those questions were more explicitly allowed.

  Here is the reasoning.

  For a few years now, once in a while, I've voted to close questions that were visibly asked by developers, but that were about configuring some existing service (for example a web server or a database server), not particularly involving any programming at all. I'm not sure this was the right thing to do.

  I have also seen and used "legacy" questions dating back to the early days of Stack Overflow, when such questions were more tolerated, in terms of subject. (Just to re-iterate, I'm only talking about questions that would be off-topic for being about sysadmin. Unclear or open-ended questions would still not qualify.)

  Unfortunately, these old questions present a problem: many of them are closed, yet they're generally useful, in particular to developers having to understand or do that bit of sysadmin to get to the next stage of the development of their application. Deleting them would be a waste. Keeping them closed serves no purpose: no one can ever add a more up-to-date or generally better answer. That's not quite as bad as fully locked, but leaving those questions closed cannot make them be an opportunity to *improve* Stack Overflow. Being closed, they'll at best not get outdated too quickly, but they're unlikely to get any better.

  Coming back to more recent questions on this sort of subject, I've realised that sometimes I would have faced similar problems, even as a developer (so I would be interested in reading answers anyway), or that I may have known the answer and could have produced an answer (remember that some of us answerers are quite happily trying to help generally). Closing those (good) questions seems to be a bit of a waste: developers are missing out on useful knowledge, because it's at the fringe of their core subject, askers and readers don't get help (and someone is likely to ask again more or less the same thing later anyway), closed questions are still visible for a while, so those who don't like these question still get to see them anyway. Dealing with them is also a waste of moderators' time. The main point here is still that *developers are missing out on useful knowledge*.

  One of the reason why Server Fault doesn't like sysadmin questions coming from developers is that they tend to expect a finished product (or something close to it). In contrast, many sysadmin questions asked by developers are mainly about getting their project off the ground, or finding a way to debug more complex applications they're developing, involving existing products.

  Software development is more than just "coding". In many cases, we need to know how to configure such and such tool or how various network settings work, simply because we need to write an application in these environment. This is useful both for setting up a development environment, and to know what to prepare for the production release.

  Even in institutions where there are dedicated teams of professional system administrators, it is often up to the developers to set up some of the services they are going to use for their application. Some settings (which would be considered as system administration, but not programming) can have a major impact in the way an application is programmed. It's also very useful to know that some settings are available (even if they're not currently used by your current sysadmin team): there can be good business cases for getting the sysadmin team to enable a feature that they normally wouldn't turn on, when it fits the purpose of the product being developed.

  I know some people complain about the fact there are too many questions being asked on Stack Overflow nowadays, and they'd consider allowing such questions to be too many. I don't think this is necessarily the case. The questions that cause the most problems are those that are bad, not those that are on the subject of system administration.

  Let's face it, there are only 530 users with the Generalist badge at the moment. This more or less implies that a lot of users tend to stay on a few tags, and ignore questions on subjects they don't want to read about. For those who don't like sysadmin questions, why not ignore them like they ignore questions on many other subjects, instead of preventing others from sharing useful knowledge in these domains?

  So yes, I think system administration questions should be allowed on Stack Overflow (and we could assume they're asked for development purposes), but bad questions and questions that don't fit the Q&A format should not.

Comment: [The Pee-Wee Herman Rule](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/the-pee-wee-herman-rule/).

Comment: @Cupcake That's not a bad rule, the problem is that it's rather a vague rule, which depends on how the reader feels. Nowadays, it's not hard to find 5 close-voters who would feel anything is on the wrong side of any grey area (if only because those on the other side of that grey area can't cancel the downvotes). Of course questions can be re-opened, but it's generally harder (negativity seems to prevail in this case), and it can also lead to another cycle of close votes. Allowing sysadmin questions coming from developers frankly once and for all would sort out that waste of time.