# Do cloud service consoles qualify as tools used primarily for programming?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26327729/1253428) that was closed because "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming". The  question was about using Google App Engine, which is a tool used primarily for programming.

There seems to be some confusion on how to interpret this rule, where the community generally interpret it differently to any possible, literal interpretation.

Do graphical consoles that provide interfaces to cloud services qualify as tools used primarily for programming?

Comment: Terms like "Nazi" have a lot of other connotations than pedantry, especially on a site like this with a large international audience.  Asking good questions is an art it takes time and practice to master.

Comment: the question now appears to be completely gone. I would suggest moving on.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, it's still there, it was simply closed and re-opened: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26327729/revisions

Comment: It is clearly not on-topic for StackOverflow (where is the code?  What is wrong with said code? No code? Wrong site), which is most likely why it was closed so rapidly.  The "closed as off-topic" includes a link to the explanation.  Personally, I would have suggested you asked on SuperUsers.

Comment: Some people think SO is about source code; some people think it's about building software. Just for the record, there was no way you would have interpreted the original question as meaning anything other pedantic. You're generalising, and that's taken it completely out of context.

Comment: @CarlSmith: He didn't say it had a lot of *denotations* other than pedantry, he said it had a lot of *connotations* other than pedantry. Using *Nazi* to mean "pedant" is like using *gay* as an insult: everyone will understand your meaning, but many people will find it offensive, and/or think less of you, and/or get distracted away from whatever point you were *trying* to make. (As you saw.)

Comment: I'm genuinely sorry if it offended anyone, but the upset caused at the time wasn't actually about Nazis at all. I asked a low quality question with a really dumb, antagonistic title [on a Monday morning], in the wrong Meta. It was a stupid mistake, and took the flak I had coming to me. I learnt a lesson and redid the question properly. That's all I can do now. To imply that my actions were equivalent to "using *gay* as an insult" is insane. If anyone else wants to deride me, can we do in chat?

Comment: @CarlSmith: Look, the real Nazis murdered millions of people in cold blood, and destroyed the lives of millions of others. This happened within living memory; many of us know people who survived the horrors of concentration camps. I don't want to make you feel bad, but you need to understand that, for many people, it is very offensive to treat the word *Nazi* as a mild insult, as though the Nazis' great crime had been sticklerism. So -- yes, it's a lot like using *gay* as an insult. It will offend neutral observers. I'm not sure why you find the comparison "insane".

Comment: OK. None of what you wrote is even remotely relevant to anything that's actually happened on Stackoverflow. Chat?

Comment: I have proposed a site a I believe would be a better home for all cloud platform related topics, please follow if you agree, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82757/cloud-computing-platforms

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on the context of the question.

If the question is, "How do I use Powershell to do *X* against the AWS API", then yes.

If the question is, "How do I sign up for AWS, GAE, or Azure." The answer is no.

If it's a programmer-y problem, it fits on Stack Overflow, even if the platform is a non-programmer's platform (non programmers do use AWS).

If it's not a problem unique to programmers -- that is, if anyone could have this problem even if they weren't a programmer, then it does not belong on Stack Overflow.

In your case, your example fits nicely in with the latter; it is not a programming question, therefore it should not be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This is a problem unique to programmers though. Who else would want commit rights to a server? +1 for a thoughtful answer though.

Comment: @CarlSmith Who else would *want* them, or who else would *need* them?  There are [CEOs with commit rights to repositories that probably have no business coding](http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/11/the-ceo-of-facebook-still-codes-on-the-side-but-tends-to-break-things/), simply because they want them. It happens.

Comment: The wording "tools used primarily for programming" does include the App Engine console though, so maybe the wording should change. My question didn't ask about the console either, only mentioned it to explain the problem. If someone posted a Web API call I could have used, that would've worked. I just wanted to change the permissions on a VM - programatically would've been fine.

Comment: @CarlSmith I'm not sure why you're surprised it was closed; as you commented on a [duplicate question yesterday that was also closed in 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15863095/remove-myself-as-a-developer?rq=1).  That said, there's always wiggle room -- but it's not surprising that it was closed, and it's not really something I'd unilaterally re-open.

Comment: The other question was different; the situation there was to do with handing ownership to another. I never owned this project. I was only an editor.

Comment: The question "How do I sign up for AWS, GAE, or Azure?" would be on-topic if it was asking how to do it with an API or CLI, but not a GUI. So my only sin was *mentioning* the GUI. The answer also used the GUI, does that make the answer wrong? This whole thing is very grey. It seems a bit much to dismiss a user's problem because it's a borderline fit for the site.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I think your example of a CEO who would have commit rights is a straw man.  The vast majority of people who would have this problem would be programmers.  By this argument not everybody who would have access to a Git repository would be a programmer.  So are you saying that questions about Git are off topic for Stack Overflow?  There's a grey line between what is and is not an on topic question.  For me this falls on the on topic side of that line.

Comment: I marked this answer as correct. It's still open to debate, but the answer is balanced, and it's not really for me to decide what's actually the correct answer here.

Comment: Just to point out that the help center says "*software tools **commonly** used by programmers*", not "***primarily** used by programmers*". The difference is subtle, but it make your argument about CEOs with commit rights fall apart, I think.

Comment: A programming tool can even be a web service - I would say.

Answer (score 8):

I think your question is indeed on topic, in that it falls within the area of "*software tools commonly used by programmers*" (see [Help Centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

Of course, it's not a programming question as such, but although that tool can also be used by non-programmers, programmers are very much one of its main user categories.

Note that I'm generally more lenient when it comes to the subject matter of the questions asked on SO, [especially for questions that involve a bit of sysadmin, even if it's from a developer's point of view](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266612/372643). 
Many users here seem to disagree, unfortunately.

It's as if developers like us who have had to do something else that pure coding during our development work (such as setting up our development environment or knowing how our programs interact with the environment into which they are deployed) were a minority.

In reality, questions like these can be considered a grey area. Purists (those who get stuck on the words "source code" and "programming") and, in fairness, reviewers who have to deal with a relatively large number of bad new questions, will inevitably vote to close them. It seems it is the way SO has become. Due to its popularity, and since there is no shortage of new questions anyway, it seems there has been a tendency to close when in doubt, even if this stands in the way of a good Q&A exchange, which might be useful to others. This is quite understandable considering the number of bad questions that appear every day.