# Is my question about a Vagrant configuration script really off-topic?

Tags: support, moderation

I have posted a question on stackoverflow inquiring about proper configuration of a Vagrantfile:
[Expose Vagrant VM to network when using NFS and private_network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26492781/expose-vagrant-vm-to-network-when-using-nfs-and-private-network)

This question was put on hold minutes later and I believe this was done in error.

The moderator said:

> "Questions on professional server- or networking-related
>   infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless
>   they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be
>   able to get help on Server Fault." – Andrew Barber

Vagrant is a tool for programmers.  My question is about Vagrant.  Hence my question is about programming.

From the help center:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people
>   who write code because they love it. We feel the best Stack Overflow
>   questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question
>   generally covers…
>
> a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm, or software
>   tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable
>   problem that is unique to software development … then you’re in the
>   right place to ask your question!

Comment: Don't just down vote, leave a comment so I know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Downvote is not mine, I fixed your title, please consider rephrasing the rest of your question so it looks less like a rant. You might very well have a point here, no need to hammer it down this way.

Comment: While we're at it, I think adding a `[ruby]` tag (or a more specific one, if available) would benefit your original question (and reinforce the idea it's about programming first, VM management second).

Comment: That reads like a network configuration question to me. I think it would be more appropriate on Server Fault.

Comment: Good idea, will do.

Comment: Bill, do you know what Vagrant is?

Comment: @Bill, from what I could gather the network configuration in question is achieved through actual code, so programming is involved. Am I wrong?

Comment: frodopwns, I know it's a tag on Server Fault.

Comment: @Bill Vagrant is using a ruby syntax to build dev environments on a local machine.  IT doesn't require networking knowledge, only ruby.

Comment: Ok my question is off hold. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Having config file written in code doesn't *necessarily* make something a programming topic. sendmail's config file uses `m4` but doesn't mean every sendmail config question belongs on SO.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, well, we can argue about the differences between scripting and macro languages all day, but in the end if SO rejects configuration modules as Ruby scripts, then it should also do the same with configuration modules in the Javascript world (where we're also fond of using the language itself to express configuration). Of course, that concept is not new, so let's get rid of Emacs Lisp and Vim config scripts. And probably also PowerShell. I don't think that goes in the right direction.

Comment: With the explanation, I think it's OK to be reopened. It really read like a configuration question to me. A quick correction/explanation fixes that every time. And just so you know, some people don't care for being called "overzealous"...

Comment: @AndrewBarber you are right I apologize.  I was nose deep in troubleshooting this issue and wasn't thinking tactfully. Thanks.

Comment: Heh... no problem; I know the feeling!

Comment: fwiw, it's not just ruby syntax. It's really ruby code and ruby programming. The fact that the code is used to create environments does not make it any less programming.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, FYI, ServerFault doesn't really like developer questions at all. They're very strict on their "professional administrator" audience. I [really think SO should be more relaxed when it comes to questions that are in between pure programming and sysadmin stuff in the context of development](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266612/372643) (but I acknowledge that may SO users don't seem to agree).

Comment: I have worked extensively with Vagrant. In fact I have the same problem like yours where I use NFS for folder sharing and need to allow network access to fellow developers in my office. I still believe this is a network configuration question rather than programming question. Lets assume the answer goes something like - 'change the IP of load balancer to 10.0.0.10 and then host addresses in VMs to match this address'. And most likely you will find an answer in similar lines. Where do you think this question should belong? Stack Overflow or ServerFault?

Answer (score 34):

I have the following question for you:

> If you remove vagrant from the equation - and you are setting up these
> machines manually, do you know how to create the network
> configuration?

If the answer to the above question is **no**, then your post is better suited on `superuser.com`, because its about how to configure a guest with dual interfaces on VirtualBox and in my opinion not suited for `serverfault.com` which is about administering servers and networks.

If the answer to the above question is **yes** - then you need to reword your original question so its more about vagrant configuration and less about the networking part, for example:

> I would like to setup two network interfaces on one machine through
> vagrant where one is bridged against the host and the other is private
> to other VMs on the same VirtualBox host. How can I set up such a
> bridge network?
>
> Manually I know I would configure the machines thus [insert the manual way to to it] but I am
> having problems trying to automate this using vagrant

Now, its directly about vagrant configuration and perfectly on topic.

As currently written, I don't blame Andrew for closing it. Personally I would have downvoted it.

Comment: I disagree with you.  Vagrant isn't about network configuration.  Vagrant is about abstracting that knowledge out of the equation so devs can focus on code rather than environments.  This question is about achieving functionality through Vagrant and nothing else.  It can't even be nailed down to VirtualBox specifically because at any time i could decide to flip a switch use Vagrant with Docker, VMWare, or Hyper-V instead.

Comment: @frodopwns, ...and Burhan's answer makes it clear that you could write your question in such a way that it was *explicitly* about building a Vagrant configuration, and not about OS-level networking configuration. Keep in mind that a question that required networking knowledge rather than language knowledge would would still be clearly and explicitly off-topic if the language were bash instead of Vagrant/Ruby, even though we answer lots of bash questions here; the dividing line is what kind of knowledge is needed to answer, not "is this useful to programmers".

Comment: @frodopwns, ...so, to reiterate: I'm not saying your question doesn't belong on StackOverflow, and as I read this answer, neither is Burhan. OTOH, writing it in such a way as to make the side of the division it's on _explicit_ can't be anything but an improvement... and given the number of folks who've misinterpreted it, it clearly wasn't explicit enough as originally asked.

Comment: @Charles I guess I felt the question was explicit enough for other Vagrant users. This is why I tagged it with "vagrant" and "ruby" rather than "networking". The problem seems to be that non-Vagrant users decided to descend on my posting and tell me what my question was about.

Comment: @frodopwns, well, yes, that happens. I'm assuming you were tagged `ruby`, not just `vagrant`? That means you get Ruby people too. Posts are viewed by folks who follow _any_ tag in it, not _every_ tag -- and that's for the better, as the inverse would result in a far smaller audience for each question, and a great many folks who could legitimately answer not being able to do so.

Answer (score -12):

No, it isn't.

This was an understandable misunderstanding.  Vagrant is closely related to networking because some of the functionality it provides deals with provisioning networks on the host.  If I had known people would see "network" and automatically think ServerFault or SuperUser I would have left that word out of the post.

This system is more closely related to a database abstraction layer.  If you have a question about Django's ORM you ask in the Python section...not MySQL (generally).