# Where can I find clear boundaries for what questions are asked on Stack Overflow, Super User, Webmasters, and Server Fault?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Last night I decided to migrate away from XAMPP to independent installations of php, apache, mysql, phpmyadmin, and mercury.

I went through hours of configuration hell, and along the way, I had a question or three I wanted to post and it brought up an ongoing sore point for me of not really knowing where to post it on the family of stack exchange sites. Is there a place where I find clear boundaries for what questions are asked on the Stack Exchange sites Stack Overflow, Super User, Webmasters, and Server Fault?

As background, I work independently, code  (php, JavaScript) and manage my own site which is on a shared host. I use Stack Overflow 99% of the time and most issues come back to code for me - and that is why I am posting this question here.

What I believe:

**Stack Overflow** is for coding issues
When my php installation was done but accessing my website gave me php errors, I imagine this is where I should ask those questions.

**Server Fault**
When my installation of php and apache just wouldn't work due to configuration issues, I imagine that this is where those questions would have gone.

**Webmasters**
I normally use this site for my SEO questions but I am not quite sure what the differences between this site and server fault.

**Super User**
I use this site for other technical issues that don't fall in the other categories. I am tempted to use this site when issues don't cleanly fit in the above forums.

Comment: Each site /help/on-topic is the most canon you can find.

Comment: @Braiam - thank you, that helps a lot. You would think that would be one of the links under "Help" - a simple "What to post on this site"

Comment: @mseifert: It's the first link when you go to the [help].

Comment: Server fault  is for [managing information technology systems in a business environment](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). This does not include questions about local install issues, or typically anything related to shared hosts either.

Comment: @zondo - Thanks, somehow I've missed seeing that link among all the other stuff on the page. Now that I've read through all the sites' " What topics can I ask about here?" links, it's clearer, what goes where.

Comment: @AD7six - Thank you, I see that now. I can imagine the reasons for this distinction (business versus development environment), but it seems to fracture up the knowledge base more than I care for.

Answer (score 8):

Just to have it in one place - this is a quick reference for anyone, or the next time when my memory isn't so clear...

**Stack Overflow**

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software
  development

**Webmasters**

- search engine optimization (SEO)
- domains
- web-hosting
- internet marketing

**Server Fault**

- managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage
  or networks
- tools used for administering, monitoring, or automating these
- deployment to and management of third-party provided information
  technology platforms

**Super User**

- computer hardware,
- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

**Information Security**

- web app hardening
- network security
- social engineering, including phishing
- risk management policies
- penetration testing
- security tools
- using cryptography
- incident response
- physically securing the office, datacentre, information assets etc.