# Include reason in fail audit message

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

Today I have failed an audit in the First Posts queue, shame on me. I have understood the reason (should be off-topic as server administration question), but it is certainly not thanks to the warning displayed.

I can't recall it exactly but I am sure someone can post it here as it seems to be a canned message. It lists all the possible reasons a post could be wrong. The way it is written sounds like I was to accept the worst post on Earth, but more importantly it does not give a clue about why that particular post is wrong. That seems to explain why so many people come here to ask why they failed.

From what I understood after some reading on Meta, the audits are automatically selected based on some criteria such as up/down votes, closed, etc. So if I am correct, it is not possible to manually attach a "reason for being wrong" to the audits. But nevertheless, for all the posts that were closed or deleted, is it possible to include in the warning the close / delete reason, so that reviewers have a better idea of why they failed the audit?

Comment: Presumably the close reason is already displayed under the question on the failed audit screen

Comment: Well, in my case the audit screen was completely hiding the question (which is something else I did not like about this message), the only way to close was to click "I understand" and go to the next review.

Comment: "should be off-topic as server administration question..." - maybe not. The "software tools commonly used by programmers" means nearly every command, program and package is on-topic for Stack Overflow. That includes servers and configurations because they are used by developers. (For completeness, I don't agree). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262881/are-website-configurations-on-topic and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262917/please-add-verbiage-in-help-center-to-reflect-policy-on-site-server-configuratio.

Comment: @Djizeus, ah I see, may well be that VLQ queue doesn't show you deleted questions after you fail (and hence no close reason) - if thats the case (as it is with answers) I agree it needs a fix

Answer (score 7):

This was the audit you failed: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5249136

Note that this question was *closed* because folks thought it might be more appropriate on [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/), but the migration was rejected. The key to understanding both the migration rejection and the failed audit can be found in what the question is lacking:

[image: you need more details]

Folks frequently ask how to improve performance of a system without being specific enough for anyone to help them. They forget to note:

- the areas in which performance is currently unacceptable
- the performance goals they're hoping to achieve
- the constraints that they must operate under while attempting to improve performance
- the steps they've already taken to attempt to improve performance

*Even then*, these questions can be difficult; there are just too many variables involved that may or may not be included in the question, but it is sometimes possible to identify a strategy when a *specific* query or configuration is described. Additionally, in common scenarios, it may be possible for answerers to outline general strategies or best-practices...

...but none of that is possible here, because we have *no idea what the actual problem is*.

When reviewing posts, be watchful for these problems, as they trouble many new askers, and do what you can to guide them toward a useful question.

Comment: Thanks for the additional hints for this kind of question. To answer my question, you are saying I could have opened the post outside of the queue if I wanted to better understand the audit failure? Fair enough. But that works only for closed questions, not deleted posts, right?

Comment: No, I'm saying you could've scrolled down and read the comments. Heck, you could've done that *before* you tried to review the post, and you probably wouldn't have failed it. Don't be in such a hurry...

Comment: I remember not being able to do anything on the page but click 'I understand', and in particular not being able to scroll so that the audit screen does not hide the question, but maybe I missed something. Anyway, you are right: I should have spent more time on reading the question.