# Can my programming-specific maths question be undeleted?

Tags: discussion

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23408572/2288578) from 2014 was deleted four years ago. I only just noticed now.

It was closed as it appears to be off-topic for SO. I respectfully disagree. The question is very specifically about calculating angles with a programming language. The answer explains how to do it using `atan2`, which is a function available in the maths libraries of most languages. If I had asked on Stack Exchange site *[Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)*, I would have received an answer I couldn't have understood and wouldn't have known how to translate into a programming language.

There's also significant precedent for programming-specific maths questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14066933/2288578) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21483999/2288578) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2150050/2288578) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17530169/2288578)

I understand that popularity isn't a reliable measure of question/answer quality or topicality, but it *is* typically a good indicator of whether people found it useful. 23 upvotes on the answer suggests to me that it was useful to a lot of people.

These days I'm much more familiar with maths and can see my question is a duplicate of any number of previous questions, but I don't believe it should have been deleted. I would like to request that it be reviewed and ideally undeleted (and then probably closed as a dupe) so it can continue to be of use to people.

---

Screenshot of the question for those without deleted-question viewing privileges:

> [image]

Comment: "_The reason I ask here and not on MathExchange is that my problem is directly a programming one_", and "_the reason I do not state a specific language is that I know many and am capable of converting between any of them_" this reasoning doesn't seem to stand, you are basically asking for a mathematical formula, since the question could be rewritten as: "What is the formula to calculate the angle given 3 points"

Comment: Your "precedents" are my "yet more off-topic questions that ought to be closed".   Stuff falls through the cracks ... and moderation standards have changed in the last 10 years.

Comment: Even if one accepts it is about programming, it seems to lack focus. "a programming language such as C++ or JavaScript" is almost all mainstream languages. Do you have a specific duplicate target in mind so that closure can be handled swiftly before the Q&A gets trashed again?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi C++ and JavaScript are only in the semi-colon, curly-braces category. Don't put everything in the same trash bin. let's try to be environmental friendly here.

Comment: The gist is mathematical, not programming: *"find the angle (0 to 360 degrees, rotating clockwise) between 0,1 and another point"*. It is also a search problem (even then it very likely was a duplicate). For example, [`https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=angle%20two%20vectors`](https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=angle%20two%20vectors). First (not necessarily high quality): *[2 Simple Ways to Calculate the Angle Between Two Vectors](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors)*. If the starting point was the formula, then it could have been on-topic. -

Comment: cont' - Then it would have been about the implementation (e.g., handling the singularities (if any), (loss of) precision, rounding, performance, programming language, alternative expressions of the formula to avoid numerical problems, etc.).

Comment: Why did the question get undeleted and reopened when that is **clearly** against the consensus here (as well as any remotely common-sense interpretation of policy)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Back then I didn't even know how to think about vectors, so it was very hard to search. It's also possible there were less resources in 2014 so search results may have been slimmer. But yes, due to my lack of knowledge my attempts to search were pretty poor.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My guess is, because there _isn't_ a consensus. There's a _majority_, but no consensus. 15 upvotes suggests opinions are divided.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Honestly, I couldn't disagree more. I can't articulate my defence but [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266359/2288578) (and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266437/2288578)) already does so excellently. I fully agree with both parts.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel _"any remotely common-sense interpretation of policy"_ That seems unnecessarily inflammatory. What policy? Because I've read [the help centre page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and it sounds pretty on-topic to me.

Comment: If I remove the last paragraph from your question and change the second last paragraph a bit it becomes a question I'd likely find an answer to on [math.se]. If I search `site:math.stackexchange.com how to find angle between 3 points` I find quite a few questions with answers a programmer could easily understand.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Honestly after doing that same search and looking at half a dozen questions I'm still not finding anything I would have come even close to understanding in 2014. It's a struggle even today. It's like I'm being given answers in French. Yes, I learned a bit of French in school, but it's going to take me days of effort to understand enough to really comprehend what the answers are saying. Do I really have to learn a whole new language just to convert the answers back to a language I understand? Why can't we just ask for answers in a language we already know?

Comment: The answer on your question is irrelevant as closure and question deletion is determined solely based on the (lack of) merit of the _question_. A bad question having an answer doesn't suddenly make the bad question good.

Comment: @Clonkex "Why can't we just ask for answers in a language we already know?" The question under discussion didn't do that.  It was asking for practically any language. Going for both C++ and JavaScript is still quite a stretch - it’s somewhat incidental that the solution is almost the same.

Answer (score 12):

This is a math question.

You're asking for an approach to a math problem. You even explicitly state you don't care what language the answer is given in.

That alone already makes it off-topic on SO.

The examples you linked are old, and SO's rules have changed since then. In fact, two of them are very similar to your question in that they're pure math questions, that should be closed.

Now, as far as deletion goes...
It's off-topic, it's a duplicate, and frankly lacks research.

Imho, that's plenty of reason to remove the question.

Comment: Does language agnosticism make a question off-topic? I don't see how that's relevant. Yes, it's a maths question, but I'm specifically asking how to implement the formula in a programming language. I struggle to see your viewpoint. It's very specifically a _programming_ maths question, which is completely on-topic. _"frankly lacks research"_ It doesn't, actually, I just didn't know what to search for. I did try quite hard to find an answer. You can't infer lack of research because not knowing != not trying. _"SO's rules have changed since then"_ Have they? I haven't seen anything about this.

Comment: What you're asking for is what mathematical functions you need to get your desired result. That's a math problem, not a programming problem. The fact that you want to put it into code is irrelevant, if you're asking for the formula itself. The question isn't about technical implementation, it's about design/process. All I'm seeing in your comments on this question here are a bunch of excuses, and none of them make the question on-topic.