# How to suggest moderator to move question to other site?

Tags: discussion, migration

I found this question [git-http-backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222992/git-http-backend), which I think is better fit for serverfault.

I've marked it to Close -> Off topic. But I don't see "Belongs to other site" option any more.

Is it correct way to do it?

Comment: Personally, I don't see any reason why this question should be migrated to Server Fault.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy This question is related to editing Apache `httpd.conf` file. Some may say it is related to programming, others may not. Here is already discussion about even more basic configurations. [Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261726/3701228) Personally, I don't think that setting git repo, and configuring it with Apache is what lot of programmers would do by themselves, rather would contact local sysadmin/linux fan to do it.  But since it cant be moved, there is really no point for long discussion ;-)

Comment: Here's another old unmigratable question that I think pretty clearly belongs on tex.stackexchange: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501182/splitting-a-bibliography-how-to-overcome-multibib-latexs-file-limitation-16-m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot migrate questions that are older than 60 days. That post is *way too old* to be migrated to any other site.

If it is off-topic here on Stack Overflow, then just vote to close.

Comment: So, what's the rationale behind not migrating old questions? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501182/splitting-a-bibliography-how-to-overcome-multibib-latexs-file-limitation-16-m) is wayyy old, but still quite relevant to LaTeX users. I won't vote to delete it, as I want that information to be available on the web, but I don't think it belongs here either. I guess I could recreate the question over on tex, but that just seems silly when there's a migrate mechanism, and it wouldn't seem right for me to be the author of it on the other side.

Comment: @drevicko: See [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151890); migrating old posts causes problems; voting on such posts reflects the old community, not the new, as do the answers.

Comment: ok, things are not as simple as they seem! Thanks for the link, and congrats on your new modship (: