# Question is closed as off-topic after being open for almost 4 years

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

Back in 2012, I asked question [json_decode fails on godaddy hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881919/json-decode-fails-on-godaddy-hosting).

The issue was a very peculiar case of a strange configuration with one particular (although rather very common) hosting provider.

The question had a +2 score and a valid accepted answer, which described the very bizarre configuration thing that was related to this hosting provider only.  The accepted answer had (and still has) +5 score.

All of a sudden, a few days ago, the question got two -1 votes almost immediately one after another and the question was put on hold as off-topic with the following reason:

> "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting."

The question clearly provided all necessary code and the problem was not caused by any typos.  I am not fussed about losing 3 rep point - I just want to understand what it is about this question that makes it off-topic?  And, most importantly, is it really off-topic? And, if yes, then why did it take more than 3 years for people to vote it as such?

Comment: This is most definitely related to the godaddy tag cleanup.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/please-help-out-with-burninating-godaddy

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, it's likely related. Ironically, my (linked) SO question was probably a rare case where [godaddy] tag was reasonable.  I do agree in general that [godaddy] tag should burn.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=32534081#32534081

Comment: @JAL I suppose, the cleanup was the reason why people started looking at old godaddy questions.

Comment: @HansPassant https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32534706#32534706

Comment: I don't see this as a programming problem... but something that your hosting provided should solve. Talk with them. They shouldn't wishfully modify what your application retrieve without telling you.

Comment: No, they shouldn't @Braiam, but since it's a simple *code* solution that solves this problem, this question is on-topic for sure.

Comment: @hichris123 oh of course, but the ticket is more effective, and don't leave you scratching your head meanwhile.

Comment: @Braiam note that this was asked almost 4 years ago - I have moved to a different hosting ages ago.

Comment: I suppose because problems like these keep popping up :P

Comment: Piggy-backing on this question, would folks be willing to [undelete this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283767/php-files-open-blank-on-my-website/22285027), apparently also caught up in the burnination? It has been closed as "unclear", which is plainly a misuse of the close system - it is not unclear at all. The user has used a backslash in a path in a PHP script, which has a specific and useful answer. (I'll ask a fresh question on this if needs be, but I don't want to create Meta duplicates unnecessarily).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was one of the close voters. I was reviewing this question for the [Godaddy burnination effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/please-help-out-with-burninating-godaddy). I voted to close the the question because, at the time, it seemed to be just an old, obscure, overly broad, server configuration issue without enough information to reasonably reproduce the issue.

Upon further review, I have decided that I believe it is a reasonable enough question. I would like to see the "For whatever reason" fleshed out, but that is wishful thinking at this point. It isn't the worst question that I have ever seen, and it has been found useful by at least a few users, so I concede that it is, in my opinion, good enough.

It does seem to be a server configuration problem at its core, the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) could be a bit more on the Minimal side than it is now, but there is a simple pure code solution to the problem.

As it is, the question can stand without the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag if the [shared-hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shared-hosting) tag takes its place. I have gone ahead and edited the tags to reflect this and voted to reopen.

The question is now open and well out of the path of the burnination effort.

Comment: Thanks.  I did gather so much that it's related to the godaddy tag cleanup. The question can certainly stand on its own without the [godaddy] tag - and thanks for the edit (I was actually editing it to do the same when you submitted your edit).

Comment: I don't mean to be overly cynical here, but the way I read your answer, it sounds like your *primary* rationale for closing it initially was the presence of the [godaddy] tag. I'm glad you have now reconsidered, but this is the problem with these kind of vigilante tag cleanups. Even well-meaning users get swept up in the hysteria. It is hard not to. Until they finally give us better tools, please keep in mind that tag burnination should not cause you to evaluate questions with a stricter standard than you normally would, and that "close all teh questionz" is not the ultimate goal.

Comment: Yes, that @Cody. I looked through the questions and saw a decent amount that were closed saying we're not customer support for godaddy -- questions that are otherwise considered on-topic. With efforts like these, though appreciated, users need to make sure they're consistently applying site-guidelines and guidelines on Meta for on-topicness.

Comment: @CodyGray That was not my rationale at all. I was *reviewing* the question because of the godaddy clean up, I was not *closing* the question because of the godaddy clean up. I voted to close the the question because at the time it seemed to be just an old, obscure, overly broad, server configuration issue without enough information to reasonably reproduce the issue. I voted to reopen because upon further review, it seems *reasonable enough*.

Comment: This is because of behavior like this that I have stopped participating in SO for the past year or so. Valid questions being closed randomly because of some overly broad cleanup initiative or someone made a wrong judgement call. If you're not 200% sure whether this is a valid question, why not err on the side of caution and leave it alone, or even ask for a second opinion? I wish there was some kind of penalty when questions get wrongly closed so we stop seeing this kind of behavior so often and drive so many people away from participating.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy I conceded that this question is not off-topic for the reason that I had originally voted to close it, but it has been since closed as "too broad", which it technically is, then reopened, because meta is meta. It has received a simple **solution** to the **problem**, which is why I believe that it is reasonable ***enough***, but it has not received an **answer** to the **question**, (remember this is a Q&A site) which is asking *why the problem exists*. We do not have enough information to reproduce the issue, so technically the **question** is too broad.

Comment: @CharlesMenguy you seem to dramatically oversee the truly monumental amount of shitty questions that **totally rightfully** get closed by said cleanup initiative. Surely if you're around since as long as you seem to imply, you've been aware of all the crap going on? I'd hazard more people stop participating because of the bad questions staying open than because of the good questions being closed, only because of the sheer numbers of bad questions.

Comment: Yeah, @Felix, that's probably true, but Charles is complaining here about the sustained efforts to clean up *old* questions that are no longer affecting anyone. No one is ceasing to participate because there are a bunch of crappy *old* questions, because the system doesn't shove those in our faces. (Unfortunately, it does when the cleanup effort is underway, which is another significant problem.) I feel like it would be much more worthwhile to focus cleanup efforts on the new crappy questions we're getting. (And most effective if we could figure out a way to prevent them from ever getting in.)

Comment: @CharlesMenguy In what way is closing questions driving users away? I don't even understand how it drove you away? You left SO because too many people are voting to close old questions during tag cleanups??

Comment: @CharlesMenguy so basically you stopped participating in SO because people do mistakes ? Sure let's have no one doing nothing, at least there will be no one complaining about mistakes .... Trolling apart, cleaning is necessary and because we're humans, we do sometimes mistakes, that's why there is meta where people can ask to reopen as it was done there. Furthermore, close vote require 5 votes, meaning he doesn't need to ask for 2nd opinion, the system expects already 5 opinions.

Comment: Guys, I think @Cody's comment is pretty on spot. Let's not pile up on Charles's case. That being said, I agree that five people being necessary to close a question does amount to five opinions, **if** there were no such thing as group effect.

Answer (score -2):

Let's turn this question around. I love to do that.

Presume that I sell an application which presents users amazing cat pictures with tons of metadata about the picture. I sell it to Jon Doe so they can put it on their site. He found an application useful to him and is going to use it. Well, it doesn't work. But Jon Doe is at least somewhat knowledgeable and he paid for the app, so support is available. Here's the support ticket:

Hi,

I bough your app to show cat pictures, but when I was testing I found that users couldn't update the pictures metadata. The server reports \.

To what support (which in this case has to be me) respond:

We've tested locally your issue, and no error occurs. Could you tell us your webserver version and php version (and whatever other libraries my app has, etc.)?

---

My server is an Apache 2.11 php 5.5. Is on a hosting provider, godaddy.

(I'm seeing something worrying there, but lets say it's not that... it can't be that)

---

We tested with the same server and php and couldn't reproduce the issue, can you tell us what options php has enabled? Put this info.php on your server and copy the output here.

---

Amazing output.

---

Well, your problem is X option, you have to tell your sysadmin to change to A. Ask Godaddy how you can change it.

---

I then proceed to open a ticket with the following text:

Add supported/tested hosting providers:

Apparently our application doesn't work OOTB with Godaddy. Can we inform our users before hand?

STATUS: FIXED

On the app page:

> This is a list of hosting providers which are known to work with our app:
>
> - a
> - b
> - c
>
> These are known to not work with our app:
>
> - Godaddy

Comment: ... even though I read the entire thing and re-read the source question, I need a TL;DR for this one to understand the point you're trying to make :)

Comment: @Gimby it isn't a programming problem.

Comment: It's a problem related to configuration of a web server, which makes it on-topic. I really don't see what this answer is trying to prove.

Comment: @CodeCaster err... when was that on topic ever? I didn't get the memo

Comment: Wow, so edgy. Try visiting the actual questions on main for once, instead of brigading on meta. Web servers are tools used by programmers, whether you like questions about them or not. See for example [Are questions about webserver config files and rewrite rules on-topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261726/are-questions-about-webserver-config-files-and-rewrite-rules-on-topic).

Comment: @CodeCaster they are a *grey area*, meaning that is a case by case basis. In this case, it shouldn't be.

Comment: And you say that based on what, the little story from your answer? A web server setting which has a direct impact on how values sent by a client end up in variables in server side code is as on-topic it can get.

Comment: IMO it becomes less of a grey area if you don't speak about programming problems but programmer's problems. The magic quotes configuration, which was 99% certain the root cause, most definitely is a programmer's problem to have - and thus makes the question on-topic.

Comment: @Gimby But you can't be sure. Yes, that's one possible cause, the other one is that Godaddy is such a sucker. And no, programmers *won't* find this issue, since they know what configuration they use in their dev environments (which is usually the default).