# Assisting with [godaddy] deletions

Tags: discussion, support, vote-to-delete, burninate-system, vote-to-undelete

There's <s>618</s> 256 [closed posts left in the [godaddy] tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgodaddy%5D+closed%3A1). I have <s>7</s> 14 daily delete votes, so that would take me <s>89</s> 19 days to vote on all the remaining posts.

Can the community help out with delete votes and if they don't think the post should be closed, it can be voted to be reopened and the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag will need to be removed.

The burnination request [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/please-help-out-with-burninating-godaddy) was met with resounding votes, so I figure there should be some 10k + users willing and able.

*It's not a duplicate of the burnination request, which had a misleading title. This is actually an appeal to have help with the final deletion. A separate question.*

Comment: Is there any way for user that does not have sufficient rep to cast delete votes(such as me), to help? Or should this task be left to the big boys.

Comment: I'll cast a few :-)

Comment: @Mr.goosberry if the question looks worth deletion and you don't have enough rep for voting delete then just vote it down. [The lower the score the easier it is generally to delete the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/165773)

Comment: Please do not vote down just for the sake of cleaning up tags. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307010/1402846

Comment: @gnat you have a comment directed at your comment

Comment: I'll quote Cody Gray: ["please keep in mind that tag burnination should not cause you to evaluate questions with a stricter standard than you normally would, and that "close all teh questionz" is not the ultimate goal."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333353/question-is-closed-as-off-topic-after-being-open-for-almost-4-years#comment388670_333354)

Comment: @BradLarson that is true, mind you, if we had unlimited votes and time, who knows what would happen to the net worth of many posts, it depends on the focus. The community overwhelmingly wanted the burn, but doesn't seem comfortable with the consequences. We are also given small tools to do big tasks and then get criticized when desperate to make the task easier. So don't blame people for using the very tools the site provides. We are allowed to vote how we please. If it is a democracy, then really people shouldn't be dictated to. A question that is off topic, can rightly be downvoted.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I don't have the rep to directly delete things, but I think I can help save some delete votes.

Avoid using delete votes on posts that will be deleted soon by Roomba.

Those with the privilege should prioritize deleting questions with an accepted answer first. Those without the privilege should focus on down voting questions that lack research effort, are unclear, etc.

Here are the relevant rules for Roomba:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> - not closed as a duplicate
> - has a score of 0 or less
> - is not locked
> - has no answers with a score > 0
> - has no accepted answer
> - has no pending reopen votes
> - has not been edited in the past 9 days

Comment: I actually think this is a good answer and it's something that I continually overlook, not sure why it was rushed to downvote.

Comment: You might have missed the comment from [Pang](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/assisting-with-godaddy-deletions#comment390544_333706). Without these warnings this answer is bad advice. @Yvette the rushed down vote is mine.

Comment: @rene well the OP can edit and add the caveat to the answer. After all the op did say `lack research effort, are unclear, etc`

Comment: Sure @Yvette but the burnination is/was headed by SOCVR and I want to make clear that our room tried the down vote aproach and was told to never do that again. Hence my statement. Everybody is free to use their votes but this is NOT endorsed by SOCVR or a policy from us.

Comment: What is this "Roomba" that you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen http://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

Answer (score 10):

I went through the last fifty Godaddy posts to be deleted [with this search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=active&q=%5Bgodaddy%5D%20closed%3A1%20deleted%3A1) (As a moderator I can see all deleted posts).

I'd like to say that all those deletions and closures were warranted. Most of them are, but some of the deletions and closures weren't. I've reversed the ones that aren't warranted, and I'll discuss those types in detail below.

Questions with the godaddy tag should remain undeleted if:

1. At the time they were asked, the subject matter was asked and answered on Stack Overflow]([Sending email through gmail SMTP on GoDaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225103/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-on-godaddy?noredirect=1)).
2. [The subject matter is reasonably something a programmer would do when programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434550/how-to-connect-livegodaddy-sql-database-to-android-app).
3. The question has upvoted answers.

Questions should remain open if:

1. [They're about a programming issue that tangentially involves Godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348068/using-godaddy-domain-hosting-to-link-to-amazon-s3-website?noredirect=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929129/can-i-dynamically-create-subdomains-php-htaccess-with-godaddy-hosting?noredirect=1) (i.e, they list Godaddy as their service provider; but it's a programming (or programmer's) issue; not a Godaddy issue)
2. [They're a programming issue that if you removed the word "godaddy", it'd still be a programming or programmer's issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22515498/entering-route53-nameservers-gives-me-errors-on-godaddy), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122863/laravel-installation-in-godaddy-hosting-how-to-prevent-accessing-public-using?noredirect=1) .

The bottom line is that simply deleting posts that contain the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) is wrong.  Some of those questions should remain by virtue of the fact they are programming questions, and others should remain by virtue of the fact that it makes no sense to delete them (they're useful, they have good upvoted answers, and people are still searching for this issue).

I checked the first 50, and out of that 50, I saw 8 that should have been handled in another way than they were handled (either by not being deleted, not being closed, or closed as a duplicate of a better answered question).

I don't really want to audit all the deletions; but if I keep seeing posts that are incorrectly deleted, I'll have to.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38434550/how-to-connect-livegodaddy-sql-database-to-android-app) has nothing to do with godaddy. It was a simple auth failure that would happen with anything that isn't localhost.

Comment: You're adding questions back into the godaddy tag. I thought you were at least removing the tag. If you are going to undo, disagree with the communities work, at least assist with the burnination. not make it harder.

Comment: Are you aware that the community voted to burn the godaddy tag? So you're overruling this and suggesting that posts pertaining to godaddy are now ontopic and should stay here?

Comment: @Yvette Are there any examples I listed where I put the `godaddy` tag back in? No. Because I don't believe the tag should exist; but I'm also not going to burn down a good question just because of a tag. If you want the tag removed, feel free to remove it; but don't burn down the forest because you think the tag diseases everything. It doesn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225103/sending-email-through-gmail-smtp-on-godaddy is specific to godaddy. so if the tag is not wanted what are we going to do with the question?

Comment: You don't need the godaddy tag there; the title has it. It's not getting any hurt juice by the removal of the tag.  And if, there are some tags that after careful consideration should still have the godaddy tag; then that's the way it is. There are very few absolutes.

Comment: Am I right @GeorgeStocker that at this point we better ask for a CM to remove the tag from the remaining closed questions? We didn't want to re-tag because that upsets other users their workflow.

Comment: @rene Nope, this is still community territory; all I'm asking is that you don't burn the forest down trying to get rid of the tag.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I find it a bit hard to implement what you ask, given that all edits, up, down, close and delete votes are done by the community given the [guidance here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332200/578411). Are you saying you want another part of the community to participate in trying to burninate the remainder of that tag?

Comment: @Yvette: keep in mind, once manual review is completed the tag can be removed from the entire system *en masse*. Y'all don't have to touch questions whose only issue is *having the tag* - the point of manual review is to allow the tag to flush out questions that need *more* attention.

Comment: @Shog9 So if we manually review the remaining 140-ish closed score > 0 as I now suggest in the [progress answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/332200/578411), which can include deletion  despite that we disagree with some mods about what is valuable, we are good to flag for a mod to carry out [step 6 of the process](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/578411). Is that what we should try in the way forward? That does mean you'll have to delete and/or remove the tag from about 480 questions.

Comment: That's not a problem, @rene.