# Reviewing the [godaddy] burnination - freeze the tag, rather than burn

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, scope, burninate-system

There is a burnination in process for [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy) There's been a plea for community assistance [Assisting with [godaddy] deletions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/assisting-with-godaddy-deletions) and out of this there is [controversy over what should be closed, deleted or retagged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333768/3956566).

There's still 336 closed questions in the tag from over 1600 questions in the tag.

This question isn't to argue whether the [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) tag is on topic. The community has made a resounding vote that it's not.

There are many questions relevant to programmers that are specific only to [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy). This makes the decision of whether a question with the tag is on topic difficult.

As, if the fact that the hosting with [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) is pertinent, and the removal of the tag makes the question not on topic for any other type of hosting, what do we do?

I suggest that we cease the tag burnination, but instead freeze it. So the tag is locked from any further questions being posted with the tag. This may or may not include some message saying this tag is not considered off topic for the site, but the questions are kept on the site as a repository for what *was* considered on topic and as such may still have use.

This takes the pressure off users trying to cope with burninations, and keeps more quality on the site, without having to try and figure out how best to re-tag it.

As a site we do not need to cover every possible facet of programming, but if it was and still if useful, although now off topic, why not keep it here?

This is actually my thought on all historic off topic questions, if there's quality there, keep them. Don't throw the baby out with the bath water.

Comment: Sounds good to me Yvette. Freeze it. Keep it. Pressure is off and we move on to greener pastures.

Comment: *"There are many questions relevant to programmers that are specific only to godaddy."* Could you maybe add some examples? I suspect that many seemingly godaddy-specific issues are actually related to specific server configurations.

Comment: @Alexander *Apparently* server configuration questions are on-topic, if you are configuring a server for the use of programming.

Comment: @drew _"and we move on to greener pastures"_ This sounds soo promising :)

Comment: How do we freeze it? I was not aware that was a feature.

Comment: A blacklist, @MikeMcCaughan - see my answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Normally, I'm not a big fan of leaving tags in limbo like this. But this appears to be a tough nut to crack; as you note, there's some pending disagreement over what questions should remain on the site, and what should be done with those that do not remain. Meanwhile, the pressure to remove the tag appears to be encouraging some sub-optimal decisions on these questions...

Given folks are *still asking questions* in this tag, blacklisting it with a helpful message seems a small courtesy to all involved. So as of now, it is no longer possible to use [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) on Stack Overflow; attempting to use it produces the following error:

> The 'godaddy' tag is not allowed.
>
> You may wish to [contact GoDaddy support directly](https://www.godaddy.com/contact-us.aspx) if your question concerns a problem specific to their system.
>
> - For programming questions that simply happen to involve shared hosting in some way, use the [shared-hosting](/tags/shared-hosting) tag.
> - For questions on the professional administration of sites and services hosted on GoDaddy, try [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour).
>
> Otherwise, please omit this tag. For details, [please visit meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy).

Comment: "You may wish to contact GoDaddy support directly if your question concerns a problem specific to their system." For this line alone, thank you.

Comment: Totally agreeing with @Braiam. It seems to be the best possible solution.