# Blacklist the [seo] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

This issue has been kicked around Meta more times than I care to count. The [seo] tag needs to no longer be used on SO.

There's a few reasons not to ask for burnination, not the least of which is that there's 6500+ questions, and some of them are historically useful and need to remain tagged [seo]. But it's obvious that the [last attempt at fixing this tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334707/provide-asking-instructions-for-seo) isn't working (this is just the front page, freehand red circles added for flavor)

[image]

As someone who has to do SEO from time to time, the reason most of these are off-topic is that SEO is actually about marketing your website to search engines and their users. That's well beyond the scope of SO.

Since this isn't an option

[image]

the next best thing is to [blacklist the tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334584/reviewing-the-godaddy-burnination-freeze-the-tag-rather-than-burn/334663#334663).

There's only two real use cases that are on-topic for SO anyways, and other tags can easily fill in

1. URL rewrites. There's tags like [.htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.htaccess) and [mod-rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite) that are highly relevant here. People ask these without the [seo] tag all the time
2. XML site maps (programs to generate them). They should be tagged [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) and [sitemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitemap)

Comment: *"SEO is actually about marketing your website to search engines and their users"* Really? And all this time I thought it was Snake Essential Oils. :p

Comment: Proposed title: "Hide [seo] from Google".

Comment: Just allow users to submit the question as normal, but automatically post it to Webmasters.SE instead. They'll love it and send us all Christmas cards for our generosity in helping them to fill their website.

Comment: @CodyGray what did Webmasters.se users did to you?

Comment: Proposed title: "[seo]: Should Exclude this One"

Comment: I think that this proposal would happen more quickly if there was a more professional blacklist message. It may be fun to just tell them to bugger off, but writing a real message means you don't have to wait for others to get around to doing it.

Comment: SEO: also known as the homeopathy of programming.

Comment: @Thunderforge [There is already a real message](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334713/1743880).

Comment: @Tunaki Good to know. I didn't realize that the other link had that message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem isn't that the SEO tag is bad. The problem isn't even that folks keep asking SEO questions in it.

The problem is that folks keep asking SEO questions on Stack Overflow.

Some of them don't even use the tag. But that does not significantly improve the questions.

So... We could ensure that *none of them* use the tag. But I'm not convinced it would actually help.

Comment: If we transform the warning into a rejection... there will be no more new SEO question... maybe 530 questions, but SEO no.

Comment: Wait, you're suggesting that we're gonna reduce SEO questions by hurting the SEO of SEO on SO?

Comment: Why, yes. No, I'm talking about [instead of a warning](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334713/1743880) just reject them. BTW, how good has been the warning in preventing new questions?

Comment: I'm not saying it will stop the SEO questions. My argument is 1. Having a tag encourages the behavior 2. It doesn't actually enhance the on-topic questions that use it. All it's doing is aggregating question closures, since most are off-topic

Comment: @mac And why is having a tag that aggregates questions in need of closure, thus making them easier to find and close, a bad thing?

Comment: Seo tag needs more murder.

Answer (score 5):

I agree. There are legitimate questions relating to SEO, but those can easily be asked without an SEO tag. I cannot thing of a single legitimate question to be asked on SO that would only be appropriate for an SEO tag. Additionally, this tag is way too broad. Questions about `robots.txt`, `nofollow`, `meta`, etc. are appropriate if asked properly, but SEO itself just opens itself up to questions like:

> I don't know anything about programming. Well, I worked in HTML once for 2 hours, if that counts. How do I make my WiX website hit number 1 on google.

This is not to say that people who don't know a ton about programming aren't welcome here, as they obviously are, but the type of people an SEO tag attracts are people that want to make no effort to learn about programming on the whole, and just want a free answer to do something that people pay lots of money for, is on the whole a relatively hard thing to do, and are unlikely to care about sticking around SO afterwards. I completely agree with the blacklist and hope this moves forward.

Comment: "Questions about robots.txt, nofollow, meta, etc. are appropriate if asked properly" [citation needed] each time I have an issue with those, Webmaster, Google support pages, etc. has better information and is more authoritative than anything SO has been able to produce (and I had several questions about that recently),

Comment: @Braiam There is nothing inherently off-topic about a question about those. I'm not saying that there are a ton of good questions about those, but there could theoretically be an on-topic question.

Comment: "There is nothing inherently off-topic about a question about those" for one, its not a question that is "unique to software development". People that has seo question maybe never developed software... if anything they just mess with configuration and/or install plugins. Programmers that has to bother about SEO, are doing so because in that moment they are something else than programmers.

Comment: @EliSadoff I disagree. If questions about SEO are a bad thing, then questions about SEO that don't have a [seo] tag are also a bad thing!

Answer (score 1):

I think that a message could be:

> Techniques and questions about how to improve the visibility of web content in search engines using an understanding of search engines' processes and algorithms are best answered on [webmasters.se].

Comment: Bit too verbose IMO `Techniques and questions about how to improve the visibility of web content in search engines are best answered on [webmasters.se].` would probably do it.

Comment: `SEO stuff be off-topic, ya hear? I hear Quora is nice.` would probably do it as well.

Comment: @TinyGiant Why not yahoo answers while we are at it?