# The GoDaddy blacklist message needs updating

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-blocklist

A couple of years ago we [burninated the godaddy tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy). Once we got down to a contentious pool of questions, there was a [discussion that ended with a blacklist.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334663/2370483)

That blacklist means user trying to add a [godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/godaddy) to their questions are greeted with the following message:

> [image]

The problem is the message points to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288200/kill-the-godaddy-tag-with-fire?noredirect=1), which has been deleted (was a duplicate). It should be updated to point to [the main burninate thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy)

Comment: That auto-redirect is horrible, click a link to your deleted post and it redirects me to "the main burninate thread", I was strugging to understand what was deleted

Comment: @NickA I guess it doesn't do that to me because of rep. Interesting

Comment: Indeed, as soon as I try to navigate to /q/288200 I get sent to /q/331817

Comment: @Machavity: What message? Do you get one when you try to ask a question with the tag? (I don't really wanna try it by posting junk)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes. It's asking instructions. Just open the Ask page and put in the Godaddy tag (no need to even try to post or write a Q). Might take a second but it will show up

Comment: The question wasn't deleted, it was merged into the other one.

Comment: Ah, I figured it wouldn't be as trivial as editing a meta post.

Comment: Yeh I can't edit the pop up itself. We need Shog

Comment: if it doesn't redirect for users who can see deleted posts, there's probably no problem or need to change it

Comment: @BhargavRao unfortunately adding the nodirect parameter to the question link didn't fix it.  It still redirects for me

Comment: @psubsee2003, Oops, then I guess the noredirect doesn't work for merged posts.

Comment: @BhargavRao Anyone without 10k cannot see the deleted post. It appears to automatically redirect for them.

Comment: @Machavity, yeah, but usually when you add the `noredirect=1` parameter for duplicate posts, it doesn't redirect.

Comment: On a related note, all of the questions in this tag are closed and the tag Wiki says that the tag is "due to be removed" - are these questions *actually* going to be removed?

Comment: @BhargavRao [Filed a bug on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314470/noredirect-1-parameter-no-longer-works-for-deleted-merge-stubs-for-10k-users)

Comment: @EJoshuaS if nobody fixes them...

Comment: @Braiam Is the plan for Shog or another CM to disappear them with the CM tool, for a mod to delete them manually, or just to 10k delete all of them?

Comment: @EJoshuaS eventually, all bad questions will be deleted.

Comment: @EJoshuaS [There was some controversy over what should be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333706/assisting-with-godaddy-deletions/333768#333768).

Comment: @BhargavRao And now it looks like the bug report has been dismissed as by design.

Comment: Hmm, weird, I always thought that it was available and never by design. Thanks for letting me know, @gparyani.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post has been edited to direct to the open and active post [Should we burninate [godaddy]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331817/should-we-burninate-godaddy). People with high rep will be directed to the open post.

[image]

Comment: need Shog to edit this

Comment: I took care of it (just made the same edit you did, so your screenshot applies perfectly).